# How can mongodb handle ObjectId timestamp beyond Tue, 19 Jan 2038?

Tags: mongodb, timestamp

As per [MongoDB official docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/bson-types/#objectid), it states that:

> ObjectId values consists of 12-bytes, where the first four bytes are a
>   timestamp that reflect the ObjectId’s creation, specifically:
>
> - a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
> - a 3-byte machine identifier,
> - a 2-byte process id, and
> - a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

I'm just wondering what's gonna happen on **Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:08 GMT** when the unix time will be equal to **2147483648** which doesn't fit the 4-byte timestamp in ObjectId **philosoraptor meme**

Answer (score 6):

Unsigned 2,147,483,648 perfectly fits into 4 bytes. 4 bytes is enough to hold values up to **4,294,967,295**, which is a unix epoch for **Sunday, 7 February 2106 06:28:16 GMT**.

If ObjectID's survive without changes till then, the timestamp part will start from 0, if you care:

```
> new Date();
ISODate("2106-02-08T12:41:20.450Z")

> db.t.insert({welcome:"from the future"});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> db.t.find().pretty();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("0001a7b306c389186a3a9323"),
    "welcome" : "from the future"
}

> db.t.find()[0]._id.getTimestamp();
ISODate("1970-01-02T06:07:47Z")
```

Comment: In other words, ObjectID cannot contain a date from *before* 1970?

Comment: @phil294 of course not. Same way system date of a *nix box cannot be set before 1970. It's why it's called unix epoch. The timestamp part of ObjectId represents timestamp when the object was created and the first ObjectId was created some 40 years after the epoch started.

Comment: Thanks! Epoch is not always strictly unsigned though, [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Representing_the_number) `If unsigned, its range in the future would be doubled, postponing the 32-bit overflow (by 68 years). However, it would then be incapable of representing times prior to the epoch. The consensus is for time_t to be signed, and this is the usual practice.`. But it of course makes sense in this context, as it's about the record creation date

Comment: @phil294 While it makes sense, is there any docs that tell how ObjectID is sorted by MongoDB? e.g. will `{_id:-1}` continue to work properly for automatically generated ObjectIDs?

Comment: @TimTIMWong, `{_id:-1}` will store `-1` in the _id field, nothing more. _id is a special field in sense that it is always present in the document, and it must be unique. That's all. No other limitations on the value.  It can be an integer, a string, an object etc. ObjectID is just the default value that drivers add to objects if _id is not set explicitly.

Comment: @AlexBlex I mean sorting by descending _id `sort:{_id:-1}` won't be messed up until 2106.

Comment: @TimTIMWong, sorry, my bad, missed the "sorted" part of the comment. If ObjectId format won't change in 80 years, then yes, it will mess up with sorting. It's very easy to test by  advancing system date to beyond 2106. I couldn't find any docs tho.

Comment: @AlexBlex Tried with 2110-12-31 just now, it throws `The value of 'value' is out of range. It must be >= 0 and <= 4294967295. Received 4_449_427_200`.

Comment: @TimTIMWong, it's not quite clear what exactly you tried. I'd suggest to post a new question with enough details to reproduce your problem. Please respect the rules and do not post your question as an answer.

Comment: @AlexBlex No, I don't have my problem. I'm answering the original question with another example that MongoDB cannot construct an ObjectID from a 5-byte timestamp.